# "Recent Apps" or "Overview screen" is not showing the recent activity on my application in Android?

Tags: android

Suppose i have 3 Activities A, B, & C.

If i go A->B->C then if i hit the recent apps button it is not showing the latest screen in the recent apps lists which should be C. However if i press Home button and then press the recent tasks is shows the Activity C. Then works fine. But then again if i got from C->B->A then again if i press the Recent tasks it shows the Activity C which should be Activity A.

i cant find the pattern of this must be some thing with the Manifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/themex">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/theme1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/themex"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

</application>
```

Comment: post your manifest code

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati added the file

Comment: which android version you are testing on?

Comment: have seen this problem on 6.0.1 and 7.0 so far.

Comment: Your manifest looks correct.so when you click on recent apps and then on your app, it opens activity C or A when you go A-B->C.

Comment: No No No... when i click on recent apps...last actvity of each application shows in stack as you can see in lollipop and later version...but in my case suppose it show the Activity A... when go from A->B->C...

Comment: strange issue. try removing `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` from activities.

Comment: i have tried this also and it doesnt work but i reckon it is for the soft keypad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out the answer after few tries...i have set

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

in my theme which causes the problem. i removed it and it works fine.